# cis- and trans-isomers in equilibrium

Tags: organic-chemistry, isomers

> Rotation of groups about double bonds are usually restricted due to large torsional strain and it is due to this reason that *cis*- and *trans*-isomers have their independent existence. However, certain structural modifications in the compound makes the rotation of groups about double bond possible and hence, for such compound, *cis*- and *trans*-isomer exist together in equilibrium.
>
> Identify which of the following compounds has such structural feature and its cis and trans isomers exist together in equilibrium:
>
> (A) $\ce{CH3-CH=CH-CHO}$
> (B) $\ce{CH3-CH=CH-CH3}$
> (C) $\ce{cyclohexyl-CH=CH-cyclohexyl}$
> (D) $\ce{CH3-CH=NH}$

Could someone explain the answer step-by-step and the theory behind it?

I think that rotation of groups about a double bond can be possible due to conjugation of double bonds, so the answer should be (A). But I am afraid I haven't completely understood the logic behind it.

Comment: Have you considered keto-enol tautomers?

Comment: I would suggest D as the H atom can easily tunnel from one side on the N atom to the other. Tunnelling cannot happen in any of the other molecules as the groups are too massive.

Comment: See also https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/60800/how-can-an-%CE%B1-%CE%B2-unsaturated-ketone-tautomerise

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Option (D) is the answer. This may be predicted by redistribution of hybrid orbital theory or simply "Bent's Rule".

Clearly, during movement of the lone pair from one sp<sup>2</sup> hybrid orbital to the other(to interconnect between the cis and trans isomers), there has to be an intermidiate transition state, during flipping when the lone pair resides in an unhybridized p-orbital. However the activation energy to achieve this intermidiate transition state is low for option (D).

Between N and H (as in the question), the electronegativity of N is higher than H. This pulls the shared electron pair in the N-H bond towards the N atom. In order to stabilize the high electron density, there is a redistribution of hybridization observed. The s character of the sp<sup>2</sup> hybrid orbital of N (forming bond with the H ) increases ( eg from sp<sup>2</sup> to sp<sup>1.8</sup>). This causes a corresponding decrease of s character of the other sp<sup>2</sup> hybrid orbitals of N, such as the one containing the lone pair. The decrease in s character is associated with a a corresponding increase in p character of the lone pair containing orbital( eg from sp<sup>2</sup> to sp<sup>2.3</sup>). Since it is easier to achieve transition from sp<sup>2.3</sup> to unhybridized p orbital (having 100% p character), in the transition state it is easier to mediate between geometric isomer, possibly even existing in equilibrium.

For further reading see this answer:

[Why are oxime geometrical isomers stable?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/26304/why-are-oxime-geometrical-isomers-stable)